# How can I respond to the width of an auto-sized DOM element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive

I have a complex web page using React components, and am trying to convert the page from a static layout to a more responsive, resizable layout. However, I keep running into limitations with React, and am wondering if there's a standard pattern for handling these issues. In my specific case, I have a component that renders as a div with display:table-cell and width:auto.

Unfortunately, I cannot query the width of my component, because you can't compute the size of an element unless it's actually placed in the DOM (which has the full context with which to deduce the actual rendered width). Besides using this for things like relative mouse positioning, I also need this to properly set width attributes on SVG elements within the component.

In addition, when the window resizes, how do I communicate size changes from one component to another during setup? We're doing all of our 3rd-party SVG rendering in shouldComponentUpdate, but you cannot set state or properties on yourself or other child components within that method.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this problem using React?

Comment: by the way, are you sure `shouldComponentUpdate` is the best place to render SVG?  It sounds like what you want is `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate` if not `render`.

Comment: This may or not be what you are looking for, but there is an excellent library for this: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Have a look at the AutoSizer component. It automatically manages width and/or height, so you don't have to.

Comment: @Maggie check out https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure also, it's a standalone library for this purpose, and wouldn't put other unused stuff into your client bundle.

Comment: hey I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269365/7974438) It's somehow a different approach and it let's you decide what to render depending on your scren type(mobile, tablet, desktop)

Comment: @Maggie I could be wrong about this, but I think Auto Sizer always tries to fill its parent, rather than detect the size is child has taken to fit it's content.  Both are useful in slightly different situations

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The most practical solution is to use a library for this like [react-measure](https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure).

**Update**: there is now a custom hook for resize detection (which I have not tried personally): [react-resize-aware](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-resize-aware).  Being a custom hook, it looks more convenient to use than `react-measure`.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Measure from 'react-measure'

const MeasuredComp = () => (
  <Measure bounds>
    {({ measureRef, contentRect: { bounds: { width }} }) => (
      <div ref={measureRef}>My width is {width}</div>
    )}
  </Measure>
)
```

To communicate size changes between components, you can pass an `onResize` callback and store the values it receives somewhere (the standard way of sharing state these days is to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Measure from 'react-measure'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setMyCompWidth } from './actions' // some action that stores width in somewhere in redux state

export default function MyComp(props) {
  const width = useSelector(state => state.myCompWidth) 
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const handleResize = React.useCallback(
    (({ contentRect })) => dispatch(setMyCompWidth(contentRect.bounds.width)),
    [dispatch]
  )

  return (
    <Measure bounds onResize={handleResize}>
      {({ measureRef }) => (
        <div ref={measureRef}>MyComp width is {width}</div>
      )}
    </Measure>
  )
}
```

**How to roll your own if you really prefer to:**

Create a wrapper component that handles getting values from the DOM and listening to window resize events (or component resize detection as used by `react-measure`).  You tell it which props to get from the DOM and provide a render function taking those props as a child.

What you render has to get mounted before the DOM props can be read; when those props aren't available during the initial render, you might want to use `style={{visibility: 'hidden'}}` so that the user can't see it before it gets a JS-computed layout.

```
// @flow

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import shallowEqual from 'shallowequal';
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle';

type DefaultProps = {
  component: ReactClass<any>,
};

type Props = {
  domProps?: Array<string>,
  computedStyleProps?: Array<string>,
  children: (state: State) => ?React.Element<any>,
  component: ReactClass<any>,
};

type State = {
  remeasure: () => void,
  computedStyle?: Object,
  [domProp: string]: any,
};

export default class Responsive extends Component<DefaultProps,Props,State> {
  static defaultProps = {
    component: 'div',
  };

  remeasure: () => void = throttle(() => {
    const {root} = this;
    if (!root) return;
    const {domProps, computedStyleProps} = this.props;
    const nextState: $Shape<State> = {};
    if (domProps) domProps.forEach(prop => nextState[prop] = root[prop]);
    if (computedStyleProps) {
      nextState.computedStyle = {};
      const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(root);
      computedStyleProps.forEach(prop => 
        nextState.computedStyle[prop] = computedStyle[prop]
      );
    }
    this.setState(nextState);
  }, 500);
  // put remeasure in state just so that it gets passed to child 
  // function along with computedStyle and domProps
  state: State = {remeasure: this.remeasure};
  root: ?Object;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.remeasure();
    this.remeasure.flush();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.remeasure);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
    if (!shallowEqual(this.props.domProps, nextProps.domProps) || 
        !shallowEqual(this.props.computedStyleProps, nextProps.computedStyleProps)) {
      this.remeasure();
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.remeasure.cancel();
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.remeasure);
  }
  render(): ?React.Element<any> {
    const {props: {children, component: Comp}, state} = this;
    return <Comp ref={c => this.root = c} children={children(state)}/>;
  }
}
```

With this, responding to width changes is very simple:

```
function renderColumns(numColumns: number): React.Element<any> {
  ...
}
const responsiveView = (
  <Responsive domProps={['offsetWidth']}>
    {({offsetWidth}: {offsetWidth: number}): ?React.Element<any> => {
      if (!offsetWidth) return null;
      const numColumns = Math.max(1, Math.floor(offsetWidth / 200));
      return renderColumns(numColumns);
    }}
  </Responsive>
);
```

Comment: One question about this approach I haven't investigated yet is whether it interferes with SSR.  I'm not yet sure what the best way to handle that case would be.

Comment: great explanation, thanks for being so thorough :) re: SSR, There's a discussion of `isMounted()` here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @memeLab I just added code for a nice wrapper component that takes most of the boilerplate out of responding to DOM changes, take a look :)

Comment: @ptim in any case I rewrote the code so that it doesn't need to check `isMounted()`

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated way to get the width of a component :/

Comment: @Philll_t which does, `react-measure` or my from-scratch example?

Comment: @Andy , just the whole process in general. Your example is outstanding, my comment is more addressing the fact that we have to call in an entire library to get a decent measurement.

Comment: @Philll_t yes it would be nice if the DOM made this easier.  But trust me, using this library will save you trouble, even though it's not the most basic way to get a measurement.

Comment: @Philll_t another thing that libraries take care of is using `ResizeObserver` (or a polyfill) to get size updates to your code immediately.

Answer (score 43):

I think the lifecycle method you're looking for is `componentDidMount`.  The elements have already been placed in the DOM and you can get information about them from the component's `refs`.

For instance:

```
var Container = React.createComponent({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    // if using React < 0.14, use this.refs.svg.getDOMNode().offsetWidth
    var width = this.refs.svg.offsetWidth;
  },

  render: function () {
    <svg ref="svg" />
  }

});
```

Comment: Be careful that `offsetWidth` does not currently exist in Firefox.

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I don't believe that's true.  What version are you running?  It works for me at least, and the MDN documentation seems to suggest that it can be assumed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: I might be wrong but last time I checked, `offsetWidth` on a `svg` element returned undefined.

Comment: Well I'll be, that's inconvenient.  In any case my example was probably a poor one, since you must explicitly size an `svg` element anyway.  AFAIK for anything you'd be looking for the dynamic size of you can probably rely on `offsetWidth`.

Comment: For anyone coming here using React 0.14 or above, the .getDOMNode() is no longer needed: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs

Comment: @couchand I don't think the OP was looking to *get* the width of an SVG element, just *set* it based upon something else, so you could revise your answer to use some other element.

Comment: note that you'll typically want to remeasure the size at least when the window resizes, as this would not be responsive at all.

Comment: While this method may feel like the easiest (and most like jQuery) way to access the element, Facebook now says "We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern instead". You should use a callback function instead of a string ref. [Info Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively to couchand solution you can use findDOMNode

```
var Container = React.createComponent({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var width = React.findDOMNode(this).offsetWidth;
  },

  render: function () {
    <svg />
  }
});
```

Comment: To clarify: in React <= 0.12.x use component.getDOMNode(), in React >= 0.13.x use React.findDOMNode()

Comment: @pxwise Aaaaaand now for DOM element refs you don't even have to use either function with React 0.14 :)

Comment: @pxwise I believe it's `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` now?

Comment: @pxwise "Note that refs to custom (user-defined) components work exactly as before; only the built-in DOM components are affected by this change."

Comment: I *so* wish I'd read this before spending so much time trying to get @Andy's answer to work in ES6. Three lines of code, instead of all that stuff that I'm sure is brilliant, but goes over my head, in my second week of React and ES6. ☺

Comment: @MichaelScheper sure, but this doesn't actually respond to changes in the element's width, it only checks the size when it mounts.  I'll simplify my answer by recommending a great library for this...

Comment: @Andy: Fair point, and recommending a library sounds good. I think some of your code is ES7, though? Which would be fair enough, but if it's possible to add a couple of words for people like me who are just starting out with React and ES6/ES7, it might help others too.

Comment: @MichaelScheper It's true, there is some ES7 in my code.  In my updated answer the `react-measure` demonstration is (I think) pure ES6.  It's tough getting started, for sure...I went through the same madness over the past year and a half :)

Comment: @MichaelScheper btw, you might find some useful guidance here: https://github.com/gaearon/react-makes-you-sad

Answer (score 6):

You could use I library I wrote which monitors your components rendered size and passes it through to you.

For example:

```
import SizeMe from 'react-sizeme';

class MySVG extends Component {
  render() {
    // A size prop is passed into your component by my library.
    const { width, height } = this.props.size;

    return (
     <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
     </svg>
    );
  }
} 

// Wrap your component export with my library.
export default SizeMe()(MySVG);
```

---

Demo: https://react-sizeme-example-esbefmsitg.now.sh/

Github: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme

It uses an optimised scroll/object based algorithm that I borrowed from people much more clever than I am. :)

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing. I was about to create a repo for my custom solution for a 'DimensionProvidingHoC' as well. But now I am gonna give this one a try.

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback, positive or negative :-)

Comment: Thank you for this. <Recharts /> requires you to set an explicit width and height so this was very helpful