# When exactly is `componentDidMount` fired?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

This is a recurring problem I have with React. The `componentDidMount` method is guaranteed to be fired when the component is rendered for the first time so it seems like a natural place to take DOM measurements like heights and offsets.
However, many times I receive wrong style readings at this point of the component's lifecycle. The component **is** in the DOM, when I break with the debugger, but it's not yet painted on the screen. I get this problem with elements that have width/height set to 100% mostly.
When I take measurements in `componentDidUpdate` - everything works fine, but this method will not fire at the initial render of the component.

So my question is - when exactly is `componentDidMount` fired because it's obviously not fired after all the browser paints are done.

**EDIT:** 
[This Stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978911/react-cant-get-correct-width-of-element-after-render) deals with the same subject:

It also references [this github conversation](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2659) that explains what happens

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371926/using-react-how-can-i-get-the-width-of-an-auto-sized-dom-element

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Inside a react component tree, `componentDidMount()` is fired after all children components have also been mounted. This means, that any component's `componentDidMount()` is fired ***before its parent has been mounted***.

So if you want to measure DOM position and sizes etc, using `componentDidMount()` of a child component is an unsafe place/ time to do this.

In your case: to get accurate reading from 100% width/height components, a safe place to take such measurements would be inside the `componentDidMount()` of the ***top*** react component.
100% is a width/height relative to the parent/ container. So measurements can only be taken after the parent has been mounted too.

Comment: This seems to answer my question! However, I'm a bit confused on how can `componentDidMount` be fired before the parent container is mounted. If there is no DOM element representing the parent, where is the component's element placed in the DOM?

Comment: Some searching around does not provide any obvious answers to this mystery, I am afraid. Probably because of react's under the hood workings. My guess is that the parent element is in already in the DOM, but that formating is only guaranteed to be finished after `componenDidMount()` is fired inside the top component.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out. When I researched, I found that react follow a graph traversal method called "Depth First Search". Check this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcKY4hjDrxk

Answer (score 7):

As you may know, `componentDidMount` is triggered only once immediately after the initial rendering.

Since you are taking measurements, it would seem you would want to also trigger your measuring when `componentDidUpdate` in case your measurements change when your component updates.

Please note that `componentDidUpdate` does not occur for the initial render so you likely need both lifecycle events to trigger your measurement handling. See if this second event triggers for you and if it has different measurements.

In my opinion you should avoid using `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` when possible.

[React Lifecycle Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is called only once when the component mounted. That’s the perfect time to do an asynchronous request to fetch data from an API. The fetched data would
get stored in the internal component state to display it in the render() lifecycle method.

Simple: It Run After Render Functions

Answer (score 2):

If you want to respond to something being mounted in the DOM, the most reliable way to do that is with a [ref callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute). For example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div
      ref={(el) => {
        if (el) {
          // el is the <div> in the DOM. Do your calculations here!
        }
      }}
    ></div>
  );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try delaying logic in `componentDidMount()` with `requestAnimationFrame()`. the logic *should* occur after the next paint.

however, we'd need to know more about your code to see why the nodes haven't been painted. i've never hit that problem. `componentDidMount()` fires right after the dom nodes are added to the page, but not necessarily after they have been painted.