# Next.js CompononentDidMount called before page loaded

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I setState show to true inside `componentDidMount` and inside render there is an `if(this.state.show == true) return(components...)` so what i want is my components should be displayed when page load is completed by next.js.

**But for some reason `componentdidmount` is called before page is displayed, and component animation starts while page is still loading.So when page is actually displayed,user catches animation at middle of it which i dont want.**

My static folder has lots of images so i guess next is loading them and thats why it takes long, but why did `componentDidMount` is called before page finishes loading ? (componentDidMount of index.js not components inside its render method)

I disabled ssr for the components but it didnt work.Page i mentioned is not fetching anything from database and getInitialProps is not used.Its just a next.js page with components inside its render method.

By the way i notice this behaviour only on production,when app is actually deployed to remote server since it takes time to load static folder.On localhost this behaviour is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `getInitialProps` will fire before `componentDidMount` is invoked.

You can prove that by `console.log` inside each of these, knowing that `getInitialProps`'s `console.log` would be loggin in your terminal.

To explain `componentDidMount` unexpected behavior you have:

Inside a react component tree, componentDidMount() is fired after all children components have also been mounted. This means, that any component's componentDidMount() is fired before its parent has been mounted.

> So if you want to measure DOM position and sizes etc, using
>   componentDidMount() of a child component is an unsafe place/ time to
>   do this.
>
> In your case: to get accurate reading from 100% width/height
>   components, a safe place to take such measurements would be inside the
>   componentDidMount() of the top react component. 100% is a width/height
>   relative to the parent/ container. So measurements can only be taken
>   after the parent has been mounted too.

[Quoted From](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056794/8861638).

Also, if you are depending on `load` events from your `getInitialProps`, then the property `show` should be measured and sent as a prop from `getInitialProps`, as:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  async getInitialProps() {
    const loadableData = await ...loadingevent;
    return {
      show: !!loadableData.data //will return true when the data arrives
    }
  }
}

render(){
  const { show } = this.props;
  if(!show) {
    return <Loading />
  } else {
    return <SomethingElse />
  }
}
```

Comment: so what is the ...loadingevent ?  static resources loaded ?

Comment: Static resources/Data from an API request. depends on what you are doing in your `getInitialProps`

Comment: i dont even have getInitialProps in my code.if next is doing it on background i dont know.when i check pages static folder when its loaded,it shows only resources its used on that page,but probably on first load it takes time becase it loads all static folder

Comment: Can you provide the code you have in `componentDidMount` I must have had the wrong idea about your question, apologizes.

Comment: componentDidMount(){ this.setState({show:true}) }           componentDidMount is called before page is loaded.so when page is displayed,components are called few seconds ago.what i expect is componentDidMount should fire when page is loaded and displayed by next.js.But while next.js is still loading page,componentDidMount is already called.

Comment: @SultanH. don't `console.log` in `getInitialProps` and `componentDidMount` run in different consoles? One runs on the terminal & other in browser console; how do we compare which one ran first?