# componentDidMount() is invoked after Virtual DOM is mounted or Real DOM is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project using React and want to get width of an HTML element, but when adding `document.querySelector(myElelment).clientWidth`in `componentDidMount()` It return an uncorrect value. I assume that componentDidMount() is invoked after Virtual DOM is mounted but  Real DOM isn't finishing yet. Is that true ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When exactly is \`componentDidMount\` fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049493/when-exactly-is-componentdidmount-fired)

Comment: @ Ilmari Karonen : Thanks, but your topic you gave isn't things that I find

Comment: @Evert : useRef is only used for stateless component, How could I do that with it ?