# How to detect if screen size has changed to mobile in React?

Tags: reactjs, responsive

I am developing a web app with React and need to detect when the screen size has entered the mobile break-point in order to change the state.

Specifically I need my sidenav to be collapsed when the user enters mobile mode and that is controlled with a boolean stored in the state within the component.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

What I did is adding an event listener after component mount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
    this.resize();
}

resize() {
    this.setState({hideNav: window.innerWidth <= 760});
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
}
```

EDIT:
To save state updates, I changed the "resize" a bit, just to be updated only when there is a change in the window width.

```
resize() {
    let currentHideNav = (window.innerWidth <= 760);
    if (currentHideNav !== this.state.hideNav) {
        this.setState({hideNav: currentHideNav});
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Time to use hooks!
If you're component is functional, and you use hooks - then you can use the `useMediaQuery` hook, from `react-responsive` package.

```
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

...

const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: `(max-width: 760px)` });
```

After using this hook, "isMobile" will be update upon screen resize, and will re-render the component. Much nicer!

Comment: You'll want to debounce or throttle that event-listener. You'll find examples of both [here](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls).

Answer (score 34):

```
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false)
 
//choose the screen size 
const handleResize = () => {
  if (window.innerWidth < 720) {
      setIsMobile(true)
  } else {
      setIsMobile(false)
  }
}

// create an event listener
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
})

// finally you can render components conditionally if isMobile is True or False
```

Comment: This works better than any useBreakpoint hook I've used.

Answer (score 18):

**Using hooks in React(16.8.0+)** refering to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862446/1075499

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(getWindowDimensions());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

Comment: This is a copy paste of another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862446/1075499
Please use reference for solutions that are not own

Answer (score 9):

This is the same as [@Ben Cohen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480053/how-to-detect-if-screen-size-has-changed-to-mobile-in-react/44481429#44481429) but after attaching your function to eventListner, also remove it on **componentWillUnmount**

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { screenWidth: null };
  this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions());
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions)
}

updateWindowDimensions() {
   this.setState({ screenWidth: window.innerWidth });
}
```

Comment: This IS the correct answer and should be marked as such. (It should also be debounced or throttled, as ivarni commented on the above answer.)

Comment: When invoking the addEventListener it should only pass the this.updateWindowDimensions reference instead of invoking it.

Answer (score 5):

#### For Next.js

Here is a custom hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useScreenWidth() {

    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(null);

    const isWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined';

    const getWidth = () => isWindow ? window.innerWidth : windowWidth;

    const resize = () => setWindowWidth(getWidth());

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isWindow) {
            setWindowWidth(getWidth());
      
            window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
       
            return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
        }
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [isWindow]);

    return windowWidth;
}
```

In a component, it returns the width size of the viewport, which can then be compared with a given numeric value

```
const widthSize = useScreenWidth()

const mobileWidth = 400

if(widthSize > mobileWidth){ 
    //logic for desktop
}

if(widthSize <= mobileWidth){ 
    //logic for mobile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hey I just published a npm package for this issue.
Check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-getscreen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withGetScreen} from 'react-getscreen'

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isMobile()) return <div>Mobile</div>;
    if (this.props.isTablet()) return <div>Tablet</div>;
    return <div>Desktop</div>;
  }
}

export default withGetScreen(Test);

//or you may set your own breakpoints by providing an options object

const options = {mobileLimit: 500, tabletLimit: 800}
export default withGetScreen(Test, options);
```

Comment: If you ask me, browsers should make it easier to get the physical screen size rather than just the resolution, since pixel densities vary so much...

Comment: In my experience components that lay themselves out based upon screen size are less reusable, because if you were to put them in a 2 x 2 grid for example, they would render as if they were the size of the whole screen rather than a quarter of it.

Comment: well, addons like these, should only be used on something like container components

Comment: Yes, they're fine for that case

Comment: how do you use it in func component?

Comment: same way. Imagine Test is a function component, the code outside the component stays the same. And within Test you would still get those functions as props.

Answer (score 3):

The react-screentype-hook library allows you to do this out of the box.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-screentype-hook

You could use the default breakpoints it provides as follows

```
const screenType = useScreenType();
```

screenType has the following shape

```
  {
    isLargeDesktop: Boolean,
    isDesktop: Boolean,
    isMobile: Boolean,
    isTablet: Boolean
  }
```

Or you could even configure your custom breakpoints like this

```
const screenType = useScreenType({
    mobile: 400,
    tablet: 800,
    desktop: 1000,
    largeDesktop: 1600
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to archive this first way is with CSS using this class

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {}
```

any class inside this tag will only be visible when the screen is equal or less than 576px

the second way is to use the event listener

something like this

```js
 constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isToggle: null
        }

        this.resizeScreen = this.resizeScreen.bind(this); 
    }
    
    
     componentDidMount() {

        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeScreen());

    }
    
    
    resizeScreen() {
        if(window.innerWidth === 576)
        {
            this.setState({isToggle:'I was resized'});
        }
        
    }
```

even with the event listener I still prefer the CSS way since we can use multiple screen sizes without further js coding.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Functional Component, we can detect screen size by useTheme and useMediaQuery.  
const theme = useTheme();
const xs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xs'));
const sm = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('sm'));
const md = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('md'));
const lg = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('lg'));
const xl = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xl'));