# Setting Conditional Spacing in Grid Container using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There are answer to this question on Stackoverflow as well as on Github but nothing helped me.

I am using  `<Grid container className={classes.listProjects} spacing={4}>` which makes issue of horizontal scroll in mobileview. What I want is this: `<Grid container className={classes.listProjects} spacing={isMobile ? 0 : 4}>`   this will get conditional spacing.
Can someone answer how to achieve it. When can I set isMobile: true , should I use useState hook ? but in that `isMobile` to `true` .
If there is another way ?

Comment: Here I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480053/how-to-detect-if-screen-size-has-changed-to-mobile-in-react

Comment: "When can I set isMobile: true , should I use useState hook ?". No need to reinvent the wheel, see the [responsive-values](https://mui.com/components/grid/#responsive-values) section.

Answer (score 4):

**v4**

```js
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";

const theme = useTheme();
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));

<Grid container spacing={isMobile ? 0 : 4}>
```

[image: Edit stoic-wilbur-565eo]

**v5**

```js
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

<Grid container spacing={{ xs: 0, sm: 4 }}>
```

[image: Edit crazy-mountain-z6ykb]