# React MUI - make a dialog appear on small screens - invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to show a dialog only on small screens. After researching I found out that there is a hook called [useMediaQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480053/how-to-detect-if-screen-size-has-changed-to-mobile-in-react) which returns a boolean if the browser meets a specific resolution.

I'm using `"@mui/material": "^5.1.1"`

This is my implementation:

```
import { useTheme, useMediaQuery, Dialog, DialogTitle } from '@mui/material';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyDialog = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDialogOpen(useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('lg')));
    });


    return (
        <Dialog open={dialogOpen}>
            <DialogTitle>This is a test Dialog Title</DialogTitle>
        </Dialog>
    );
};
```

However this is giving me the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:

It seems it doesn't allow me to use hooks instide the `useEffect` hook.
How can I fix it otherwise, in order to achieve the same result, which is to update the `useState` state true or false according to the resolution of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use hooks inside a hook call (`useMediaQuery` in the callback of `useEffect`) even though you can use hooks inside another hook definition.

Fix it by moving `useMediaQuery` to the top level of `MyDialog` component.
Then use the output value in `useEffect`.

```
import { useTheme, useMediaQuery, Dialog, DialogTitle } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MyDialog = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("lg"));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setDialogOpen(matches);
  });

  return (
    <Dialog open={dialogOpen}>
      <DialogTitle>This is a test Dialog Title</DialogTitle>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hook should be called only on top level

> You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:
>
> ✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component. ✅
> Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.

```
const theme = useTheme();    
const mediaQuery = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('lg'))
```

Try to do `setState` only on mount **to avoid infinite re-renders**, Since you're computing browser specification `setDialogOpen` can be set once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setDialogOpen(mediaQuery);
},[]);
```

Read more about your error [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)